# How do you earn special costumes in TDS?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

If you look at a bitizen in TDS, you can change their appearance.  You are also given the option of using a special costume.

I've noticed that I have an inventory of these, but I have no idea how I earned them.

The numbers seem to change without purchasing them with bux.

Does anyone know how these are earned?  I assume it has something to do with the number of ? visitors wearing those costumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably earn them when you evicted bitizens that were wearing a special costume. ;)

Comment: Good thought.  Hadn't occurred to me.  Hopefully someone can confirm.